# Mtg creature spells, instants, priority?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

A Friend and I were playing a game last night.
I tapped 4 mana, and I had 4 Creatures in my graveyard to help reduce [Ghoultree](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGhoultree%5d)'s mana cost. So I summoned him, my friend then cast an instant that exiles creatures from my graveyard. Does Ghoultree then fizzle, because I now don’t have enough mana to cast it?

Or because he wasn’t countered he still enters battlefield because I am the active player and have priority?

Answer (score 16):

Your Ghoultree will still resolve fine; your opponent can’t prevent it by exiling cards from your graveyard after you have cast Ghoultree.

The casting cost of a spell only matters when you are casting it. You declare your spell, put it on the stack, pay it’s costs; and only then does your opponent have a chance to respond.

Your opponent could have cast his instant earlier; before your main phase, but he would have had to know that you were planning to cast Ghoultree. There is no time between you declaring you are casting Ghoultree and you paying the cost where your opponent can act.

Answer (score -1):

During your turn, if the stack is empty and you're not moving to another phase, then you *and only you* have priority. This means that you are the only person that can do anything. When you go to cast a spell, naming it, revealing it, and paying for it all happen (I forget the specific order, though).

*Once all of that happens*, you can either hold priority to do something else, or you can pass priority. *Only then* can someone **respond to what you've done**, but not to prevent you from doing it, except by countering it. Because of that, no one can ever remove your ability to cast a spell or activate an ability before you have a chance to do so when you can legally do so.

Edit: fixed some stuff; I wrote the original response on my phone, hence the errors.

Edit 2: if you want to move to your next phase, then there is a passing of priority before that happens; this is usually done by way of a shortcut, e.g. by saying, "Move to combat/second phase/end step," at which point your opponents can either do nothing or respond by doing something before moving to the proposed phase *because they have been given priority*.

Comment: I assume by "attack" you mean "stack"? This sentence is misleading, because either player could have priority while the stack is empty. The active player gets priority first in each phase, but that doesn't mean that you and only you have priority while the stack is empty.

Comment: I fixed it to what, I believe, is more correct: unless you're moving to another phase, if nothing is on the stack, there is not a scenario where anyone can have priority except you. Am I wrong? If not, can the -1 get removed?

Comment: I was not the downvoter. I don’t think “moving to another phase” is clear; moving to another phase is simply what happens after each player passes priority while the stack is empty. It is not a period of time; it is a single event. The game can be in a state where it is my main phase on my turn; the stack is empty; and my opponent has priority. This happens whenever the active player passes priority while the stack is empty. So it’s not true that it can only be the active player’s turn to act.

Comment: But how/why are you passing priority? You can just pass priority because you feel like it, it has to be...triggered, for lack of a better term, by something. Yes, passing to another phase is an event, not a period, but you can't move to another phase *without* passing priority, and that is the only time that priority *can* be passed while the stack is empty. In other words, you say, "Move to combat/second main/end step," and someone says, "In response..." That is the passing of priority which, again, needs a specific trigger to happen. When else is the active player able to pass priority?

Comment: Saying "move to combat" is only proposing a shortcut. The actual steps that happen are that active player first passes priority, which gives other player priority. Then other player passes priority, which causes the game to move to the next phase. You don't jump straight from having priority to going to the next step. If you are playing without shortcuts at all, then at the start of your main phase, you would say "I am passing priority", after which your opponent would have priority.

Comment: In other words, passing priority as the active player is NOT declaring that you are moving to the next phase. It just so happens that it is a common shortcut to say that you want to move to the next phase.

Comment: Better way of clearing it up... you seem to think that if my opponent wants to play an instant in my main phase, then he waits until it is moving to the next phase and responds by playing his instant. This is not correct; rather first I get a chance to act in my main phase, then he gets a chance to act in my main phase. If both of us choose not to act, then the game moves to the next phase.

Comment: Yes, I'm making use of a shortcut, but the fact of the matter remains: you cannot pass priority willy-nilly. There is a passing of priority before moving to the next phase, whatever it is. Therefore: if it's your turn and the stack is empty, the only reason you would not have priority is if you had passed it, and the only time you CAN pass priority *when the stack is empty* is when you are *about to* move to the next phase. In this case, then yes, if the stack is empty, the opponent *does* have to wait until moving to the next phase to play their instant if they want to do so during that phase

Comment: Oops, apparently in the comment above I said, "You **can** just pass priority..." when I meant, "You **can't** just pass priority..." Hopefully that's as clear as mud now.

Comment: Yes I actually assumed that that part was a typo. I still think that it’s wrong to say “you can’t just pass priority”... any time you have priority, whether the stack is empty or not; you can pass priority. That’s one of the things you can do with priority. Yes, the game will move to the next phase if both players pass priority while the stack is empty, but you have the cause and effect reversed. The game moves to the next step _because_ you pass priority; it’s not the game being about to move to the next step that allows you to pass priority.

Comment: “117.3d If a player has priority and chooses not to take any actions, that player passes. If any mana is in that player’s mana pool, they announce what mana is there. Then the next player in turn order receives priority.”

Comment: I still think that it's s distinction without a difference: while passing priority may be the trigger that sends you to your next turn, **that's the point of what I'm getting at**: if it's your turn and the stack is empty, you cannot pass priority unless you, by extension, are ready to move on to the next phase. Hence the statement: if it's your turn, and the stack is empty, nobody can take any action until you pass priority *because you want to move to the next phase*.